# Internet check over android.net.NetworkCapabilities not working

Tags: android, networking, wifi, android-wifi

I have a question about `android.net.NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET`. According to the JavaDocs this "indicates that this network should be able to reach the internet".

Unfortunately this seems not to work properly - or I do something wrong here. I outputed the value of capabilities for three different Wi-Fi networks:

1. A Wi-Fi with internet access.
2. A Wi-Fi without internet access (I manually disabled the internet here).
3. A public hotspot (the "Telekom" hotspot)

In all three cases the capabilities value is `[ Transports: WIFI Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN LinkUpBandwidth>=1048576Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=1048576Kbps]`.

This is my code:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network);
boolean capability = capabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET
```

The boolean value is always `true` when connected with some Wi-Fi.

If it is relevant, the device I've tested is running under Android 5.0.1 (API 21). I compiled the app to API level 23.

Comment: why would the value be false?

Comment: I would have expected the capability `NO_INTERNET` in case a Wi-Fi does not provide internet. But even if no internet is provided the capability `INTERNET` is set.

Comment: So you want to know if the wifi network is connected to the internet?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to make a ping for this. I want to use the build-in check from Android.

Comment: Have you found solution for non working of NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET ?

Comment: how sad that this still doesn't work properly 3 years later, does anyone have any solutions? other than ping

Answer (score 14):

For devices with API 23+ you can check flag [NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities.html#NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED%20/)

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private static boolean hasInternetConnectionM(final Context context) {
    final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    final Network network = connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork();
    final NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager
            .getNetworkCapabilities(network);

    return capabilities != null
            && capabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET) && capabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED);
}
```

I check it on different devices and it works right. Except Xiaomi Redmi 3S MIUI 8 - it returns NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED for Wi-Fi without internet access.

For API < 23 I use ping.

Comment: `capabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED)` returns true on an Android Wear API 26 emulator even when there is no Internet Connectivity. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: this doesn't work correctly when you switch from wifi to mobile data connection

Comment: @Ultimo_m I am using NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR type check and then it works

Comment: This method seems to work reliably on the emulator even sitting behind a corporate proxy. If the proxy requires a new log in, this code will detect the issue and return false. I observed a bit of delay when this happens though. So, there is a little time window when the system thinks there is Internet, but there is not.
To the best of my knowledge, if you need to know about Internet connectivity as soon as possible, then trying to check if a socket connection to a given IP (e.g. 8.8.8.8) is possible would be my recommendation, according to what I observed.

Comment: checked this on Pixel 3 and also have NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED but failed with network request

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, you can't rely on NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET && NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED, you can just turn off the internet on your wifi router (by cable or programatically) and check - both of those parameters will be true even after a long delay.