# Listening to Internet changes (No Network Detection)

Tags: android

Would registering the following listener notify your app when internet connectivity changes or only when network connectivity changes?

I need to get notified when the internet goes on or off even if the phone is still connected to the same network.

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.internetconnection_demo.InternetConnector_Receiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Intent filters for broadcast receiver -->
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: There's no public framework in Android that tracks internet connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Lollipop (API 21) or later, I wouldn't go the BroadcastReceiver route. Try something like this instead:

```
fun monitorWifiConnection() {
    var connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager = getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val builder = NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addTransportType(android.net.NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
    connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(builder.build(), getConnectivityManagerCallback())
}

private fun getConnectivityManagerCallback(): ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback {
    connectivityManagerCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        override fun onAvailable(network: Network?) {
            //Connected to wifi
        }

        override fun onLost(network: Network?) {
            //Lost connection to wifi
        }
    }
    return connectivityManagerCallback
}
```

By excluding the `NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR` option and including `NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI` you should get notifications about the wifi connection exclusively.

Comment: But would this trigger the callback on Internet on/off even if I'm still connected to the WIFI?

Comment: Do you mean the cellular network? See the last note I added below the code snippet. You can choose to monitor cellular network or wifi or both. This request only monitors the wifi.

Comment: Let's say the following scenario happened.
- I'm connected to my wifi at home.
- I'm still connected to the wifi, but the wifi access point itself lost internet connectivity.

Would the callback happen in this case?

Comment: Yes that's how it should function

Comment: I think NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED flag might be required on top (only API 23+) cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41063539/93974