# Android WorkRequest NetworkType constraint can't tell between VPN with internet and without

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I have a `WorkRequest` that I want to run when the device has an internet connection. [Constraints](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work#constraints) seem to be the way to do this - I can define a `NetworkType` constraint like so:

```
val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build()
```

However, I have observed some behaviour for devices which use a VPN. When the VPN is active, it appears that the `WorkRequest` considers this as `NetworkType.CONNECTED`, even if the device does *not* have an internet connection.

Is there any way to make the constraint work as I expected?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Please first check what Network Capabilities the VPN has:

[Internet check over android.net.NetworkCapabilities not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358531/internet-check-over-android-net-networkcapabilities-not-working)

Then compare to this one:

**INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&VALIDATED**

This is what **NetworkType.CONNECTED** means.

If you want you can dump the JS and see your exact capabilities that you are waiting for like this:

**adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler**

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/debugging

Comment: Ok, so I checked the NetworkCapabilities while connected to the VPN with _no_ internet connection, and all of INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&VALIDATED are true. Which explains why the `WorkRequest` is running even when there is no internet connection. So is there any way to make the `WorkRequest` only run when there is an internet connection?

Comment: hm, so I ended up coming up with a workaround - in the Worker `doWork` method, I first check for actual internet connectivity (with `TRANSPORT_WIFI|TRANSPORT_CELLULAR|TRANSPORT_ETHERNET`), and if there is none, I let the worker retry with backoff.

Comment: great :) There was a way in the JS to pass a set of Capabilities, but I could not find such a thing for the WorkManager. I also observed some problem with a VPN on ours where there was no execution at all, because the TRUSTED was not satisfied. So VPN is tricky.

Comment: Yes, the VPN is also causing some strange behaviour when checking for internet connectivity via transport. When connected to the VPN and to wifi, `TRANSPORT_WIFI` is not present on my actual device, but _is_ present in the android emulator. Quite strange. I've resorted to using the deprecated `connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting` to check for internet, as it doesn't seem to have this problem.

Comment: @Liam I'm seeing this too (for a user who is using Blokada, which uses a VPN, and which causes the problem you report here with the `NetworkType.CONNECTED` constraint).  Did you ever figure out a solution to this, other than to use the workaround you mention... which really isn't ideal?  I have found that the `NetworkType.UNMETERED` constraint does seem to work as expected, i.e. the work doesn't run when WiFi is off, but runs immediately that it comes back on.  But I need `NetworkType.CONNECTED` to work properly too :-/

Comment: I did not, unfortunately. Another possible workaround is to [send a ping out to something](https://etherealmind.com/what-is-the-best-ip-address-to-ping-to-test-my-internet-connection/) (e.g. the Google DNS server). It seems to be the most reliable way I've found to check for internet connectivity.